# Taking Paypal SandBox Live. How to Take Live?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Maybe a silly question, but how do we take a sandbox account live?  I created an app but only have key and secret for sandbox.[PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction : @"AaQfaBBct1BMqsNwxjz6bQCXeRGvMVwcehMMCaPrjo8rJbbXL689N2VsFsTZ", PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"AU4WnBAfmhjhySUoflYW70EZBvFNfrgel3cPrB1d4-S4HiKiulsjDHWNtV_f"}];http://www.tbldevelopmentfirm.com

Answer (score 0):

They have [Going Live Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/) that should help.